# Having an Event payload be a generic object

Tags: c#, .net, generics, prism

I have code like this:

```
public class TabActivationRequestEvent<T> : 
             CompositePresentationEvent<TabActivationRequest<T>>{}

public class TabActivationRequest<T>  
{
    public IOMStudioTab OMStudioTab { get; set; }
    public T RegionData { get; set; }
}

public void RequestTabActivation<T>(TabActivationRequest<T> tabActivationRequest)
{
    var prismEvent = eventAggregator.GetEvent<TabActivationRequestEvent<T>>();
    prismEvent.Publish(tabActivationRequest);
}
```

I use this to send out a Prism event (via the event aggregator).

However, when I go to subscribe, I have a problem.  This is what I tried to do:

```
void OtherClassCtor()
{    
     var tabFocusEvent = eventAggregator.GetEvent<TabActivationRequest<T>>();
     tabFocusEvent.Subscribe(OnTabFocusRequest, true);                 ^
}                                                                      |
                                                                       |
private void OnTabFocusRequest<T>(TabActivationRequest<T> regionData)  |
{                                                                      |
     // do stuff here                                                  |
}                                                                      |
                                                                       |
This part Fails -------------------------------------------------------+
```

The compiler says I can't user a type parameter there.  When I stand back and look at it, it makes sense.  (The current class knows nothing about any type parameter).

But defining the type there is a deal breaker for me, so I am just going to use an `object`.

But this got me to wondering if there was any kind of fancy coding that would allow me to pass the generic type through the event system.

If you know of anything, then please post it.  If not, I will be happy with my `object` and my casting.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, it does not work because the `OtherClass` has no generic type parameters on its own to supply to `TabActivationRequest`.

Obvious solution would be to make `OtherClass` generic. Otherwise, you can use reflection to call the `GetEvent` method. Check out `MakeGenericMethod` of `MethodInfo` type - MSDN contains some helpful [hints and an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Of course, you still need to somehow get hands on the type you want to call `GetEvent` with.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either make the OtherClassCtor class generic, or provide a type for your generic TabActivationRequest inside your GetEvent call.